# Quitting Fasthosts and Need a Managed Email Provider

Tags: email, exchange-server

Fasthosts email service has been down all day so both us and our clients have been without email. Not really good news for a web development company. Even their site is down!

After the fiasco the other year with them losing everyones passwords it is time for a change.

Does anyone know of a good managed email reseller account we can get?

We dont want to have to administer an exchange server so a managed system would be ideal.

A manager saw this company.

[http://www.heartinternet.co.uk/reseller-hosting/][1][1]: http://www.heartinternet.co.uk/reseller-hosting/

Anyone know if these guys are and good or of anyone else?

Cheers

Steve

Comment: Not programming related.

Comment: And that statement isnt answer related ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

http://www.microsoft.com/hosting/catalogs/business-email.mspx